# How to set MediaStore openOutputStream offset in Long?

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore

I am trying to download a file to download the directory in Android 10 and above. I did as following.

```
val resolver = contentResolver
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "CuteKitten001")
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Download/PerracoLabs")
}
val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
val outputStream: OutputStream? = if (uri == null) null else resolver.openOutputStream(uri)


hiper.get("https://httpbin.org/image", isStream = true)
    .ifException { e ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: ${e?.message}")
        }
    .ifFailed { response ->
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed")
    }
    .ifStream { buffer, byteSize ->
        if (buffer == null) {
            outputStream?.flush()
            outputStream?.close()
            Log.d(TAG, "Done.")
        } else {
            outputStream?.write(buffer, 0, byteSize)
        }
    }
    .finally { response ->
        Log.d(TAG, response.text.toString())
    }
```

In `outputStream?.write(buffer, 0, byteSize)` line the offset takes an integer, but I want to use a `Long` so that I can download files larger than `2GB`.

Comment: You better make a loop where you read some bytes in a buffer and then write the bytes in the buffer to out. Buffer size < 10 K.

Comment: Even if you download the file at once in a big buffer you could use a loop to write that buffer in smaller chuncks to out.

Comment: Ok, say for example I am downloading a 4GB file and I downloaded 3GB, if I want to resume that download, I want to set the offset to 3GB (in bytes) but it will be above an integer can hold.

Comment: Who is talking about resume a download? That is something completely different.

Comment: That's what I mean by offset, I want to start writing the bytes from a specific location in a file. If the offset is Long I can move the offset anywhere I want, but it's an Int, so I can not move further than 2 gigabytes.

Comment: That is to begin with impossible with your output stream.