# How to save bitmap to Storage in KOTLIN (Media.insertImage ==> insertImage is deprecated in Java, also Media.DATA ==> DATA is deprecated in Java)

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore, android-external-storage, insert-image

**In KOTLIN**, all alternatives have been tested but a bitmap image could not be saved to an ***External Storage***

If I use:

**MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage**(this.contentResolver, file.absolutePath, file.name, file.name)

Then, I got  "**insertImage is deprecated in Java**"

If I use:

values.put(**MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA**, file.absolutePath)
context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

Then, I got   " **DATA is deprecated in Java** "

Also

**Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated**

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use insert() to obtain an uri. Open an outputstream for the uri and compress your bitmap to it. Android Q?

Comment: It is in Android Studio 3.5.3  I used these codes given by Bao Lei at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624756/how-to-save-bitmap-to-android-gallery   
  ( begins with  private fun saveImage () ).  @blackapps, thanks. Could you pls write codes, I did not understand your suggestion

Comment: To avoid getExternalStorageDirectory (since it is deprecated), I put val directory = File(this.applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath + folderName).  BUT, what should be written to solve "DATA is deprecated" problem ?

Comment: Have a look at posts with tag `mediastore`.Add such a tag to your post too please.

Comment: Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59991109/download-large-file-with-mediastore-android-10

Comment: Thanks, but, unlike the example,  there is no url like " https://httpbin.org/image" to get. Users are cropping images and then they will save to external storages. What can be put instead of this url ?

Comment: You dont need that piece of course. You have your bitmap. Now read my answer again. And you still did not tell if you on Android Q. Mentioning Android Studio makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, but, I am new and dont know how to see whether it is Android Q or not? I can see only its version from the Help tab

Comment: Then what do you see on that tab?

Comment: Android Studio 3.5.3
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548, built on November 15, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Comment: Look in `build.gradle (Module app)` file instead.

Comment: And there is a difference for which Android version you develop and which Androifd version runs on your device or emulator.

Comment: When I look at the module level build.gradle file, I can see  builtscript version for kotlin as   ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'  and dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. The image is downloaded. But, there is a runTime error: Didn't find class "android.provider.MediaStore$Downloads" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.MyApp1-VBKZXuhcU730d_pAAr65Pg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.MyApp1-VBKZXuhcU730d_pAAr65Pg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.MyApp1-VBKZXuhcU730d_pAAr65Pg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]

Comment: The image is downloaded to Phone>Android>Data>com.example.MyApp1>files>MyFiles.  But, I could not find solution to this runTime error at this line ==> this.applicationContext.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues).      Why it  Didn't find class "android.provider.MediaStore$Downloads" on path: DexPathLis ?

Comment: Please post your complete code. In your post. Not as comment. Also post the stacktrace in your post. You made it all unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trully understand what you need you should look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage).
 But if you worried that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated you can use `Environment.getRootDirectory()` or `Environment.getRootDirectory()`

Comment: Thanks, I can get fullPath without using getExternalStorageDirectory(). The problem is insertImage() is deprecated. So, I am trying to download or save with alternative ways. But, I have not saved or download it in KOTLIN. Please help me